# Detect single color overlay area with ImageMagick

Tags: image-processing, image-manipulation, imagemagick

I have a bunch of images that have a single color overlay with some text on it positioned at the bottom. Not all images have the overlay and the overlay is not of the same height on every picture.

I am looking for a way to detect the overlay rectangle, and crop only the part of the image without it.

Trim seems the logical way to go, but the text on the overlay makes trim remove only the part below the text.

Any ideas would be welcome.

Thanks!

Comment: I was trying to do it with the cl tools

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a copy of the image and crop it to just the left-most 5 pixels (assuming that there's some left margin to the text), trim and find out the new height.  Then use the height of that trim to crop the original.

Comment: Nice one, now I'm hoping the margins are uniform across all docs. Thanks!

Comment: Actually, this doesn't work for images that have a single-color background. I have an idea how to fix that though.

Comment: No dice with that idea. Any more ideas Lou? Thanks!